# How do Web Components and the Shadow DOM prevent leaky CSS across components?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

In 2008 our team investigated [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) - a technology for writing web components for Javascript in Java which would compile down.

A new member of the team said:

> You will have a problem with the CSS of the component and the page clashing with each other.

It turned out he was correct.

I was having a conversation with a friend today about [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components). I asked him how you stop the CSS of the page and the components clashing with each other.

He said:

> With Web Components and the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) it is all under control. It solves the problem of leaky CSS.

My question is: **How do Web Components and the Shadow DOM prevent leaky CSS across components?**

Comment: have you read documentation on this topic? Good starter is: https://www.dannymoerkerke.com/blog/web-components-will-replace-your-frontend-framework

Comment: may I ask you if question is really about "Why"(what was intention) instead of "How"(how does it do that)?

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful

Answer (score 2):

Because Shadow DOM was designed ***precisely*** to solve problems met when developping Web Components, as stated by Google in the [introduction to Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom):

> Isolated DOM: A component's DOM is self-contained (e.g. document.querySelector() won't return nodes in the component's shadow DOM).
>
> Scoped CSS: CSS defined inside shadow DOM is scoped to it. Style rules don't leak out and page styles don't bleed in.
>
> Simplifies CSS - Scoped DOM means you can use simple CSS selectors, more generic id/class names, and not worry about naming conflicts.

It is achieved by CSS Scoping with the introduction of a new, separate DOM tree called the *Shadow DOM*, that will locally replace the initial DOM called the *Light DOM*.